# Heroku run cp -r is trying to run on the wrong git remote

Tags: git, heroku

I tried to run this command on Heroku.

```
heroku run cp -r /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin doctor_app/static/
```

And I got this error.

```
▸    Error: Could not find git remote /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin in /home/adil/Code/mezino/DocTest/doctor_app
▸    remotes: heroku
```

Any Idea, Why ?

Comment: Try ```heroku run "cp -r /path/to/ /files/"```?

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks @JackBracken You can Answer it.

Comment: And I think title of this question is not appropriate. If you come up with some more specific title. Plz edit the question as well, So other people might be able to find it @JackBracken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku uses different git remotes to separate environments, so I believe it is interpreting the -r flag in your command as the remote to run on. Sticking the command in quotes will force it to interpret that whole block as one argument.

`heroku run "cp -r /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin doctor_app/static/"`